# File extension from MIME type with ;charset=UTF-8

Tags: python, http, mime-types, content-type

I have a Python web crawler which is downloading files with different extensions. To get the extension from the HTTP header content type, I am using the Python library [mimetypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html#module-mimetypes1).

```
http_header = session.head(url, headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'})
extension = mimetypes.guess_extension(http_header.headers['content-type'])
```

Everything is working fine, except when the HTTP header content type contains
`;charset=UTF-8`. E.g. `mimetypes.guess_extension` is returning `None` for the following examples

```
content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8 # extension should be .txt OR  
content-type: text/x-c;charset=UTF-8   # extension should be .java
```

Check with mimetypes:

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> print(mimetypes.guess_extension('text/plain;charset=UTF-8'))
None
>>>
```

**Question: How do I handle this and get the correct extension from content-types ending with `;charset=UTF-8`?**

I guess it is not a good solution to catch such exceptions with an if statement since I never know if the whitelist is complete or whether I am missing some content-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to deal with that is to split the MIME string and get only the first element.

The following code will return the expected result for both conditions.

```
http_header = session.head(url, headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'})
extension = mimetypes.guess_extension(http_header.headers['content-type'].split(";")[0])))
```

Remember it is a guess. You can't expect much from it for such broad definitions such as plain text. It seems like mimetypes.guess_extension() just takes the first element of this list. This is also the reason guessing the mimetype of text/plain returns .h when .txt is the obvious choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this doesn't work. For `text/plain;charset=UTF-8` I get `.ksh` instead of `.txt` as a result. For `text/plain;charset=UTF-8` I get `.c` instead of `.java`.

Comment: It's exactly what the function's name says, it is a guess. You can't expect much from it for broad definitions such as plain text. It seems like mimetypes.guess_extension() just takes the first element of this list. This is also the reason guessing the mimetype of text/plain returns .h when .txt is the obvious choice.

Comment: You would think a dict lookup would be better than a "guess".  For example, image/jpeg -> jpe.  That's pretty awful.

Comment: @mobiusinversion it's a guess because there is no official standard for mapping mime types to file extensions.  They're system specific and can easily be re-mapped on most systems.  They've never been strongly related and have changed over the years.  Case in point `image/jpeg` was much more common as `.jpg` but three letter extensions are commonly discouraged these days: `.jpeg` is often preferred.  I remember systems commonly using `.jpe` also.